# Get X and Y point within bitmap using OnTouchListener

Tags: android, bitmap, coordinates, imagemap, ontouchlistener

I put a bitmap on the screen and  want to make it so that when you touch a certain point on that bitmap something specific to that point happens. To do this I need it so that when a point on the bitmap is touched the x and y of that point on the bitmap are returned.

Example

[image]

I want it so that if you touch his bicep the word bicep pops up and if you touch his chest the word chest pops up.

I need this to work on different sized screens to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share answer if you find anything.

Answer (score -2):

Say your image is in an `ImageView` called `bitmap`.

```
bitmap.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener{
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev){
    float x = ev.getX(); //the most recent x coordinate of the touch
    float y = ev.getY(); //the most recent y coordinate of the touch
}
});
```

Other than this, it might be easier to overlay your image with transparent rectangle regions acting as interactive buttons which show text when touched on. This way you don't need to deal with potential coordinate unmatch between screen coordinate and the coordinate you want on the image.